# Why one needs to create a new objects on each iteration of a loop when populating a List?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am working list of objects. My code looks something like this

```
public class emp
{
   public string emp_name{get;set;}
   public int emp_id{get;set;} 
}

List<emp> emplist = new List<emp>;
emp empobj = new emp();
// fetching data from data table
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // initialize emp object
    empobj.emp_name = row["emp_name"].ToString();
    empobj.emp_id = (int)row["emp_id"];

    // add empobject to emp list
    emplist.add(empobj);
}
```

If 2 records are fetched from table then my list shows last record details in each list object.

what i found was if i dont create new emp object every time and add to list it overrides the previous value in list also.

solution for this is

```
// fetching data from data table
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
     // create new object every time
     emp empobj = new emp();

    // initialize emp object
    empobj.emp_name = row["emp_name"].ToString();
    empobj.emp_id = (int)row["emp_id"];

    // add empobject to emp list
    emplist.add(empobj);
}
```

Can any one please tell me why is it so?

Comment: In the first example, you were assigning the values to the same object. So, values were being over-written.

Comment: I've changed title of your post - feel free to revert/edit if you don't like the change.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't create a new Emp object every time, you overwrite and insert the same object every time.

Imagine a piece of paper. You write on it, you put it into a book. Writing on the same piece of paper and putting in into the book multiple times will just not work. It will be a mess of writing on a single page. For every page you need a new piece of paper.

Answer (score 1):

When you add to the emplist, you are adding 'empobj', which is a reference to a emp object.

Unless you create a new emp object each time, and assign that new entry to the empobj reference, you are just adding the same reference again and again.

Therefore, when you change the contents of that one reference, you change all the entries in the list.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are creating a single instance of the `emp` class, overwriting the elements in it for each row, and saving multiple references to *the same object* into the list.

You need to change the code to:

```
List<emp> emplist = new List<emp>;
// fetching data from data table
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    // initialize emp object
    emp empobj = new emp();
    empobj.emp_name = row["emp_name"].ToString();
    empobj.emp_id = (int)row["emp_id"];

    // add empobject to emp list
    emplist.add(empobj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In basic terms, your first piece of code effectively does this:

```
emp empobj = new emp();
empobj = new emp();
empobj = new emp(); // "final" version of the object

emplist.Add(empobj); // Same (final) added each time.
emplist.Add(empobj);
emplist.Add(empobj);
...
```

Your last piece of code effectively does

```
emplist.Add(new emp()); // New object each time.
emplist.Add(new emp());
emplist.Add(new emp());
...
```

**2 Sidenotes:**

You might want to simplify your code like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{        
    emplist.add(new empobj{ 
                            emp_name = row["emp_name"].ToString(),  
                            empobj.emp_id = (int)row["emp_id"]
                           });
}
```

..and you might want to stick to naming conventions to make your code easier to read and understand; that is, use `Emp` for class name (capitalized). The same goes for properties, but there, avoid the underscores (this is to separate them from fields and other variables):

`public string EmpName{ get; set; }` and `public int EmpId{ get; set; }`.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `emp empobj = new emp();`, you create a new instance of `emp`.

This line of code tells the memory allocator to assign memory to the new instance of `emp` object.

In your first example, you only had one instance, and you were over-writing the properties value in the **foreach** loop.

In the second example though, you were creating a new instance of `emp` object within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

We could say that List stores references to objects, that's why in first case we add same reference, but in second case we add references to different objects, because **empobj** in each cycle is a new object.